# How to edit masterDetailView template to allow custom cells within tableview

Tags: ios, swift, custom-cell

I have created a custom class called CustomeTableViewCell which includes the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
```

Within my master view controller I have two bits of code displayed below.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let coursework = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    configureCell(cell, withCoursework: coursework)

    return cell
}

   func configureCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell, withCoursework coursework: Coursework) {
    cell.textLabel?.text = databaseTest.name

}
```

My question is how can I edit this piece of code to allow multiple labels within the cofigureCell. so the function looks like this :

```
  func configureCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell, withCoursework coursework: Coursework) {
       cell.label1.text = databaseTest.name
       cell.label2.text = databaseTest.surname

  }
```

I am quite new to swift coding therefore any feedback is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you dequeue your cells, you should cast them into CustomeTableViewCell.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomeTableViewCell
```

Then by changing the cell type in your function, you'll be able to set all labels.

```
func configureCell(_ cell: CustomeTableViewCell, withCoursework coursework: Coursework) {
```

Comment: Thanks using what you said I have gotten it to work.